# json file to google line charts using django

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, charts

I'm trying to load the following JSON file into google charts. Its a line chart example with a range filter. I'm running Django on my local machine.

```
{
"cols": [
{"id":"","label":"year","type":"datetime"},
{"id":"","label":"Random","type":"number"}
],
"rows": [
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,05,22,14,08,10)"},{"v":43.876102}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,05,30,11,48,29)"},{"v":20.585972}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,37,56)"},{"v":31.891496}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,38,56)"},{"v":24.312917}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,39,56)"},{"v":54.969267}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,40,56)"},{"v":79.654599}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,41,56)"},{"v":6.719683}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,42,56)"},{"v":20.647257}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,43,56)"},{"v":7.509945}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,44,56)"},{"v":18.551308}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,06,03,14,45,56)"},{"v":38.763882}]}
]
}
```

Here is my html template:

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      line chart
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});

    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
             document.getElementById('dashboard'));

         var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
           'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
           'containerId': 'control',
           'options': {
             // Filter by the date axis.
             'filterColumnIndex': 0,
             'ui': {
               'chartType': 'LineChart',
               'chartOptions': {
                 'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                 'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
               },
               // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
               // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
               'chartView': {
                 'columns': [0, 1]
               },
               // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
               'minRangeSize': 86400000
             }
           },
          });

//   
        var chart;

        var serverData = $.ajax({
          url: 'static/json/data.txt',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(ServerData) {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable(ServerData);
            chart  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
           'chartType': 'LineChart',
           'containerId': 'chart',
           'options': {
             // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
             'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
             'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
             'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 100}},
             'legend': {'position': 'none'}
           },
         });
          dashboard.bind(control, chart);
          dashboard.draw(data);
          }
        });

      }

      //drawVisualization()
      //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <div id="chart" style='width: 915px; height: 300px;'></div>
        <div id="control" style='width: 915px; height: 50px;'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
​
```

Here is some of my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATIC_FILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
    )
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^home$', 'xtpc_project.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^LineGraphFromJSON$', 'xtpc_project.views.LineGraphFromJSON', name='LineGraphFromJSON'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
                            document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 
                            document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I put the JSON file in `venv\src\static\static\json`
`manage.py` is in the `src` folder.

I get a blank html browser when I run the dev server.
Browser tools say "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/json/data.txt 404 (NOT FOUND)
I did run python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: In your ajax call, `json/data.json` should probably be `/static/json/data.txt` (it depends on your static files settings, which you haven't shown. Once you get it working, you could try using the `static` tag). If you use your browser tools, it should be able to tell you whether the request to load the ajax is working or not. This will tell you whether you need to focus on debugging your static files config, or your javascript.

Comment: I'm seeing in the browser tools:   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/data.json 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATIC_FILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
    )

Comment: Please update your original question, you can't format code in the comments so it's hard to read. As I said before, you probably need to change the URL in your ajax call. You might find the [static files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) useful.

Comment: thanks Alasdair, this is my first ever stack overflow question. I tried your changes with no luck ( now updated)

Comment: Note that it should be `STATICFILES_DIRS`, and you are missing a comma after the `os.path.join()`. Try printing the values of your settings, to make sure that is.  `os.path.join()` gives the expected result.